# Joomla display submenu on mouse over

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I have Joomla 2.5 website. It has some built in functionality to display menu and submenus. It works fine, but I need to show submenu items on mouse over menu item. I cannot do this, because submenu items are not generated.

Is there some option to change this - so that Joomla will generate all menu items, including invisible submenu items? In this case, I can write some javascript to display submenu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu module has an option to "Show Sub-menu Items". Enable this and they will show :-)